# Find: $ \lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin 4x}{1-\sqrt{2} \cos x}$ (no L'Hopital)

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

> Find: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin 4x}{1-\sqrt{2} \cos x}$ (no L'Hopital)

By L'Hopital it is easy to show that this limit is $-4$. But I'm not finding the right approach to prove without using it.

Hints and answers appreciated. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Are we supposed to use the definition of the derivative?

Answer (score 5):

Transform your expression like this:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\sin 4x}{1-\sqrt{2} \cos x}&=\frac{2\sin 2x\cos 2x(1+\sqrt{2}\cos x)}{1-2\cos^2x}\\&=\frac{2\sin 2x\cos 2x(1+\sqrt{2}\cos x)}{-\cos 2x}\\&=-2\sin 2x(1+\sqrt{2}\cos x)\end{align}$$

then let $x\to\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 4):

Use $$\sin4x=2\sin2x\cos2x=2\sin2x(2\cos^2x-1)=2\sin2x(\sqrt2\cos{x}-1)(\sqrt2\cos{x}+1).$$
I got $-4$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\frac{\sin(4x)}{1-\sqrt2\cos(x)}&=\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\frac{2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)}{1-\sqrt2\cos(x)}\\&=\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\frac{4\sin(x)\cos(x)\bigl(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)\bigr)}{1-\sqrt2\cos(x)}\\&=\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\frac{4\sin(x)\cos(x)\bigl(2\cos^2(x)-1\bigr)}{1-\sqrt2\cos(x)}\\&=-\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}4\sin(x)\cos(x)\bigl(1+\sqrt2\cos(x)\bigr)\\&=-4.\end{align}

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585787/limit-of-a-trigonometric-function-lim-x-to-frac-pi-3-dfrac1-2-cos/2585838#2585838 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584352/limit-lim-x-to-frac-pi3-frac-sinx-frac-pi31-2-cosx/2584357#2584357

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use $x=t+\pi/4$ that brings the limit in the form
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(4t+\pi)}{1-\cos t+\sin t}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{-4\sin t\cos t\cos2t}{1-\cos t+\sin t}
$$
and use that
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\cos t+\sin t}{\sin t}=
1+\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-\cos t}{t}\frac{t}{\sin t}=1
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$F=\cos A\cdot\lim_{x\to A}\dfrac{\sin4X-\sin4A}{\cos A-\cos x}$$

**Method**$\#1:$

$$F=-\cos A\cdot\dfrac{\lim_{x\to A}\dfrac{\sin4x-\sin4A}{x-A}}{\lim_{x\to A}\dfrac{\cos x-\cos A}{x-A}}-\cos A\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{d(\sin4x)}{dx}_{(\text{ at } x=A)}}{\dfrac{d(\cos x)}{dx}_{(\text{ at } x=A)}}$$

**Method**$\#2:$
$$F=\cos A\cdot\lim_{x\to A}\dfrac{2\sin2(X-A)\cos2(x+A)}{2\sin\dfrac{x-A}2\sin\dfrac{x+A}2}$$

Now use $\sin2(X-A)=2\sin(x-A)\cos(x-A)=4\sin\dfrac{x-A}2\cos\dfrac{x-A}2\cos(x-A)$